# ActiveRecord select by last character of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried

```
members = Member.select(:member_id[6] == "1")
```

and

```
members = Member.select(member_id[6]: == "1")
```

and

```
members = Member.select("member_id[6]" == "1")
```

I am trying to get only those members where their member_id final character is a 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you want, efficiently, you'll need to leverage Postgres' string functions in a literal SQL condition. Your existing code is also confusing `select`, the Active Record method that alters what the query uses in its `SELECT` clause, with `select`, the Ruby Enumerable method, which allows you to filter a collection. Since your filtering is best performed in the database, you'll want to instead use `where`.

So, something like:

```
Member.where("RIGHT(member_id::varchar, 1) = '1'")
```

Comment: Now I am getting an errorActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function right(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "members".* FROM "members" WHERE (RIGHT(membership_i...
                                                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.:     Do I have to change the field to text?

Comment: @user125272: my apologies; I forgot the second argument to the RIGHT() function, which dictates how many characters to return. In this case, you just want one. See my updated answer for the corrected version.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!